# Elasticsearch - Is it possible to create histograms without having the field indexed

Tags: elasticsearch

I come across the following phrase
https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/tune-for-disk-usage.html

```
 For instance if you have a numeric field called foo that you need to run histograms on but that you never need to filter on, you can safely disable indexing on this field in your mappings:

PUT index
{
  "mappings": {
    "properties": {
      "foo": {
        "type": "integer",
        "index": false
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Does it mean aggregations like histograms can be created though the field is NOT indexed ?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, that's correct and that's easy to test:

Create the index:

```
PUT index
{
  "mappings": {
    "properties": {
      "foo": {
        "type": "integer",
        "index": false
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Index a sample document:

```
PUT index/_doc/1
{
  "foo": 23
}
```

Run an histogram aggregation:

```
POST index/_search
{
  "aggs": {
    "histo": {
      "histogram": {
        "field": "foo",
        "interval": 10
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Results:

```
  "aggregations" : {
    "histo" : {
      "buckets" : [
        {
          "key" : 20.0,
          "doc_count" : 1
        }
      ]
    }
  }
```